# How to use ArrayList while adding something to another Class's constructor ?

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, io

I'm try to create one simple reservation system, we'll read a file, then we'll add Train, Bus, etc., then we'll writer everything to output.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Company
{

private static ArrayList<Bus> bus = new ArrayList<Bus>();
static int buscount = 0, traincount = 0;
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{

    FileParser();
}
public Company()
{

}

public static void FileParser()
{

     try { 
          File file = new File(); //i fill this later
          File file2 = new File(); // i fill this later
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); 
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file2); 
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis)); 
          BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos)); 
          String line; 
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        { 
            String[] splitted = line.split(",");
            if(splitted[0].equals("ADDBUS"))
            {
                bus.add(buscount) = Bus(splitted[0],splitted[1],splitted[2],splitted[3],splitted[4],splitted[5]);
            }

        }
     }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) { 

        } 
        catch (IOException ioe) { 

        } 
     }
}
```

I try to read the file line by line. For example one of the line is "ADDBUS,78KL311,10,140,54" I split the line for "," then i try to add every pieces of array to Bus' class' constructor but i couldn't figured it out.

My Bus Class is like `
public class Bus extends Vehicle{

```
private String command;
private String busName;
private String busPlate;
private String busAge;
private String busSpeed;
private String busSeat;

public Bus(String command, String busname, String busplate, String busage, String busspeed, String busseat)
{
    this.command = command;
    this.busName = busname;
    this.busPlate = busplate;
    this.busAge = busage;
    this.busSpeed = busspeed;
    this.busSeat = busseat;
}

public String getBusName() {
    return busName;
}

public void setBusName(String busName) {
    this.busName = busName;
}

public String getBusPlate() {
    return busPlate;
}

public void setBusPlate(String busPlate) {
    this.busPlate = busPlate;
}

public String getBusAge() {
    return busAge;
}

public void setBusAge(String busAge) {
    this.busAge = busAge;
}

public String getBusSpeed() {
    return busSpeed;
}

public void setBusSpeed(String busSpeed) {
    this.busSpeed = busSpeed;
}

public String getBusSeat() {
    return busSeat;
}

public void setBusSeat(String busSeat) {
    this.busSeat = busSeat;
}

public String getCommand() {
    return command;
}

public void setCommand(String command) {
    this.command = command;
}
   }
```

can someone show me a way to solve this problem?

Thank you,

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: i couldn't call the Bus' class' constructor to add the words that i split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the keyword `new` to create a new instance of the class:

```
bus.add(new Bus(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add items to `ArrayList` like this

```
bus.add( new Bus(splitted[0],splitted[1],splitted[2],splitted[3],splitted[4],splitted[5]));
```

you were missing `new` keyword before `Bus` constructor call. Then you can increment the counter (or do whatever)

```
bus.add( new Bus(splitted[0],splitted[1],splitted[2],splitted[3],splitted[4],splitted[5]));
buscount++;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add new Bus(...)

> bus.add( new
>   Bus(splitted[0],splitted[1],splitted[2],splitted[3],splitted[4],splitted[5]));

Answer (score 0):

As I understand if you want to call constructor you need to call `new` `Bus(parms)`.
when you say `new` it will call constructor of your class

---

when you say `this()` again it going to call enclosing class' constructor

---

if you say `super()` it will call super class' constructor.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it into a map order by counter you can use this:

> Map(Integer, Bus) busPosition = new HashMap<>();
>
> busPosition.put(buscount, new
>   Bus(splitted[0],splitted[1],splitted[2],splitted[3],splitted[4],splitted[5]));